# Is "state" a reserved word in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, reserved-words

I tried the React documentation, but couldn't find anything about reserved words. I was wondering: is `state` in React a reserved word?

Comment: No keyword comes to mind that are reserved in React specifically. JSX is a superset of JavaScript which mostly adds HTML-like syntax to it.

Comment: I was wondering how setState works, which led me to this question, for what it's worth. @Kaca992 below answers this particular question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No state is not a reserved word. I don’t think there are any specific to react but there are reserved keywords in javascript language.

Comment: At this [Pen](https://codepen.io/i2801/pen/zKGvzB), when I replace all the "state" words, things stop working. I'm confused and clearly missing something.

Comment: @RogerB.H. `this.state` is a property of a `React.Component` class, which you can't change and still expect it to work. The React code behind uses it, if you change it, React doesn't know about your new key and it doesn't provide a way to customize it unfortunately.

Comment: Yes in class components `state` and `props` are properties of the context, i.e. `this`.

Comment: @MuhammadAli, So, in class components `state` and `props` are reserved words?

Comment: @RogerB.H. it's not that it's reserved, it's just that it is how the [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) is defined.

Comment: not exactly but you can’t directly rename state and props from context of the component.

Comment: Let me see... Can I put it this way? In the context of a **React.Component**, yes, the `state` is a "reserved" word and one must not change it. But, anywhere else in one's React project, the word `state` can be used, even if it makes the code a bit confusing?

Comment: @RogerB.H.  Redux also uses the word `state`, but it's not the same React state. `state` is a generic word, use it whenever it makes sense to you and just be careful not to overwrite/shadow an existing property or variable. ;)

Comment: I marked this answer as correct because of all the collaborations in the comments.

Answer (score 6):

State is simply a property inside React.Component. Nothing special about it.

Comment: Well, there is something special about it. It's not a keyword as such, but within a react component, it effectively is like a keyword, in that it's already defined. setState will be looking for a thing called "state" to do its state-setting.

I'm kind of a beginner at React, so I'll gladly take correction if this comment is inaccurate.