# Are props.children or children reserved words in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

How and when to use children elements is pretty clear to me, but are `props.children` or `children` reserved words in ReactJS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59955647/is-state-a-reserved-word-in-react

Comment: React is a _library_, not a _language_ - JavaScript is the language, its reserved words are listed in e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#reserved_words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my knowledge `Props.children` is a React protocol for sending child elements to a component; it is not a reserved word. You may give children components to a component just like ordinary props by using the special prop called `children`. It is used to reduce confusion and make the code more readable. `Props.children` or destructuring: `{children}` can be used to access it in a component.

---

Note: `Props.children` can include anything, including additional React components, strings, integers, or even functions.

Comment: Thank you @BouncyBits ! That mean we can say that "children" is a convention to help programmers read/write React code?

Comment: My question came from the fact that I tried to replace "children" with another word which led to an error

Comment: It's not a "convention"; as the OP has seen you can't use a different name if you prefer. It's the _API_, children of a React component in JSX are passed to it as the `children` prop. See e.g. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-props-to-a-component#passing-jsx-as-children.